# Restrict access to DynamoDB from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have a service where I have long running jobs. Each job has a GUID. I store information about that job in dynamodb and use the job GUID as the partition key. There's an EC2 instance associated with each job (and some extremely untrustworthy code running on the EC2 instance). **I want to make it so that the EC2 instance associated with a particular job can only have access to the entry in dynamodb associated with that job.**

What I was trying before was to tag an EC2 instance with the job GUID then use something like whats below to compare dynamodb leading keys with EC2 tags.

```
{
    "Sid": "UpdateDynamo",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:720911909616:table/test",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
            "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                "${aws:PrincipalTag/job_guid}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work because "PrincipalTag" refers to the IAM role and *not* the EC2 instance.

What is a good solution to this?

Comment: You can use `ec2:SourceInstanceARN` condition key . Sample policy is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: you can try the `${aws:userid}` substitution variable in the IAM role policy. See details here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve this with a single policy/role, because there is no AWS-wide condition key that will evaluate to the tag of the EC2 instance that you can use to compare to `dynamodb:LeadingKeys`.

Given your use case, I would therefore suggest setting up a serverless solution (probably a Lambda function) that, for each job:

- Creates a role
- Creates a policy that will allow the `dynamodb:UpdateItem` only for the GUID of that particular job
- Assigns the role to the appropriate EC2 instance

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the tags. The proposed solution, however, doesn't scale well enough because of the at most 5000 roles per account.

Comment: @FailureGod Well, you should obviously delete the role as soon as the EC2 instance is done running its job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `${aws:userid}` substitution variable (e.g. `"dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${aws:userid}"]`) to match with `role-id:ec2-instance-id` (see details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#principaltable)):

> - `role-id` is the unique id of the role, e.g. `AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q`
> - `ec2-instance-id` is the unique identifier of the EC2 instance, e.g. `i-0d64a3039064255a2`

So your DynamoDB table primary key would look like:

> AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q:i-0d64a3039064255a2